# Run taichi lang canvas on web browser

Tags: python, web-applications, graphics

I want to integrate my Taichi Lang real-time fluid simulation within a web application. I'm not sure how to approach this, I can't wrap it in an api and continuously fetch the results as it's too computationally heavy, is there a package or any other approach that I can try?

I already tried to make a fast api app and fetch it continuously but it's a real time interactive fluid simulation, doing this is not feasible.